# iOS8 when to alloc init CLLocationManager to call requestWhenInUseAuthorization?

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, ios8, cllocationmanager

When i try to alloc init my CLLocationManager inside the getter of it i do not get the pop up request for location autorization. But when i put inside of my viewDidLoad it does work.

My code is looking like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; //when i put this here it works
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if(![CLLocationManager authorizationStatus])
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [self.mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

But when i do the alloc init like this it does not work:

```
-(CLLocationManager *)locationManager
{
    if(_locationManager) _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    return _locationManager;
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have a logical error in your accessor method:

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager
{
    if(_locationManager == nil) _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    return _locationManager;
}
```

Comment: You should probably also set the delegate on creation and check the exact authorisation type

Comment: Thanks i just forgot the ! in the if statement.. Didn't see that thank you